# How to get children of a node in redisgraph?

Tags: cypher, directed-graph, redisgraph

[This is a directed unweighted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qifvX.png)

I created this directed unweighted graph in redisgraph but at the time of traversing I am not able to fetch the children of A. Is there any command in redisgraph to get the children of A? Since the graph is fully dynamic, I don't know the exact nature of children of A. After getting the list of children I can match their property and fetch perfect node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node 'A' needs to be identified somehow, e.g. an attribute.

Using the Cypher query language one can get A's children by issuing the query:

`MATCH (A {id:'a'})-[]->(X) RETURN X`

Assuming 'A' has an attribute 'id' with the value 'a' than X represent all of A's direct neighbours.